# Connecting to Azure KeyVault via SPN

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault, service-principal

I need help accessing an Azure KeyVault via Service Principal. I currently have two subscriptions that need to communicate and access the other subscription's Key Vault but in order to do so I would need the connection to occur via SPN. I have looked at the documentation for `Get-AzureRmKeyVault` and it provides no way to authenticate via a SPN from what I can find.

If anyone has a solution I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I think you are looking for [`Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azps-3.8.0)

Comment: Actually what do you mean `access keyvault`? Access what of the keyvault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what actually do you mean `access keyvault`, in azure keyvault, there are `Management plane` and `Data plane`, they use different access control mechanisms.

If you want your service principal to do `Management plane` operations(e.g. set the tag of your keyvault), you need to give it a role in `Access control (IAM)` of your keyvault in the portal. If you want to do `Data plane` operations(e.g. operate on the keys, secrets, certificates in the keyvault), you need to add your service principal with correct permissions to the `Access policies` of the keyvault.

For more details about access control of keyvault, you could check - [Secure access to a key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault).

So make sure your service principal already had the correct permission, then use the command below.

```
$azureAplicationId ="<application-id>"
$azureTenantId= "<tenant-id>"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<client-secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal
```

Then you can do the `Management plane` operations like [`Update-AzKeyVault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/update-azkeyvault?view=azps-3.8.0), or the `Data plane` operations like [`Get-AzKeyVaultSecret`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-3.8.0).

To access the keyvault in a different subscription, just use the command below to select subscription.

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription <subscription-id>
```

---

And I notice seems you are using the old `AzureRm` module, it was deprecated and will not be updated anymore, I recommend you to use the new `Az` module, follow [Migrate Azure PowerShell from AzureRM to Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-3.8.0).